# Test Client-Side JS with Tape (Window not defined)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, leaflet

I'm trying to implement unit tests for my leaflet plugin and my current choice is to use tape.
Unfortunately as soon as I require leaflet in my test:

```
var L = require('leaflet');
var test = require('tape');
```

I get:

> ReferenceError: window is not defined.

I had the same problem with AVA. On the leaflet Github repo the only thing I found was [this issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3220) which doesn't really help. [Lots of leaflet plugins have tests with tape](https://github.com/search?q=require+tape+leaflet&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93), so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in setting it up.

Can you guys point me in the right direction?

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to run your test in a NodeJS environment with `tape`. The Leaflet plugins using tape you've linked are either using `karma` (as `leaflet` does) or `tape-run` to make the test run inside a browser. I haven't tried yet, but interested, to run the tests with `jsdom` but it should be doable. So, either you use `tape-run` or some test runner to make the tests use a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but one of the search results has `tape-run` as dependency. Maybe it is the right direction: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tape-run

Comment: that worked, thank you! Sucks that I need browserify for it though.